# ReactWebViewManager error after upgrading to 0.60.5

Tags: android, react-native, webview, react-native-webview

After upgrading from react-native `0.59.10` to `0.60.5` we are getting this error when building Android:

```
/workspace/mobile-custom-webview/mobile-custom-webview/android/src/main/java/invisionapp/customwebview/CustomWebViewManager.java:27: error: package com.facebook.react.
views.webview does not exist
import com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager;
                                       ^
/workspace/mobile-custom-webview/mobile-custom-webview/android/src/main/java/invisionapp/customwebview/CustomWebViewManager.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
public class CustomWebViewManager extends ReactWebViewManager {
```

The custom webview is created according to the documentation: `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/custom-webview-android`

Excerpt from CustomeWebViewManager.java:

```
...
import com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.Map;

@ReactModule(name = CustomWebViewManager.REACT_CLASS)
public class CustomWebViewManager extends ReactWebViewManager {
...
```

React Native version:

```
  info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14.6
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 37.35 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 8.16.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.4.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
      Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.2, 25.0.3, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.0, 28.0.0, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
      System Images: android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245
    Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
    react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5
```

In package.json we have:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-webview": "6.8.0"
  },
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1. Create an Android CustomWebView following the documentation: `https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/custom-webview-android`
2. try to build Android by doing `react-native run-android`

Describe what you expected to happen:
Android app should build and run just like before (0.59.10)

0.60 react-native doc page:
[image: doc page]

Comment: Update: I tried to replace:

```
import com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager;
```

with

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
```
I'm getting the same error:
```
/workspace/mobile-custom-webview/mobile-custom-webview/android/src/main/java/invisionapp/customwebview/CustomWebViewManager.java:27: error: package com.reactnativecomm
unity.webview does not exist
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were able to fix this issue. Here are a few pointers:

- read the [Autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) doc carefully!
- if it is a stand-alone module (like it is the case for us) then you
  need to inlude react-native-webview in:
  the `build.gradle` of the module

```
implementation project(":react-native-webview")
```

and in the `settings.gradle` of the consuming app

```
include ':react-native-webview'
project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')
```

even if in the consuming app, it is supposed to be autolinked.

also, you need to add a file called `react-native.config.js`in the
consuming app:

```
const path = require('path');

  module.exports = {
   dependencies: {
     'mobile-custom-webview': {
       root: path.resolve('../mobile-custom-webview'),
     },
   },
 };
```

in the Java file that defines the CustomWebView:
replace:

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewPackage;
```

with

```
import com.reactnativecommunity.webview.RNCWebViewManager;
```

and then finally, a few methods have different signatures, for example: ReactWebView --> RNCWebView